# older half and younger full. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does it mean when someone says?

> I am the middle child, older half and younger full

Comment: Could you please post more of the context?  As written, it means nothing.

Comment: @Andrew https://youtu.be/J7L0WkbQwH0?t=903

Comment: It's not idiomatic English, and should not be used as an example sentence.   I don't understand the Korean so I can't even guess what it's supposed to mean.  Again, it might make sense with some further explanation, but by itself it's just  meaningless babble.

Comment: I’m guessing that the older sibling is a half sibling (shares one parent with the middle child) while the younger sibling is a full sibling (shares both parents with the middle child). But I agree with @Andrew that this is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Mixolydian  Yeah, that might make some sense, but it's not really anything a native speaker would say.  It's not a context that is commonly abbreviated in this way -- instead I would give a full explanation.  *"I'm the middle child, more or less.  I have an older half-brother and a younger 'full' brother"*.

Comment: It means that you have two siblings, one older and one younger. It also means that your younger sibling has both the same parents you have, but the older has one of your parents, and another parent that is not related to you. Half-brothers and half-sisters are related to you biologically (by blood), but by fewer people. This is distinct from Step-brothers and step-sisters, who are related to you legally, because one of your parents married one of theirs, but you are not biologically related.

Comment: Note that the phrase as provided, would sound clever and perhaps a little mischievous, but would be colloquial. it is not grammatically correct as it is, but most people would think it is succinct and quick-witted, because it makes the person who hears it think a second to understand that you are referencing both siblings without having specifically made them objects in the sentence. Instead, you simply implied that you have an odd number of siblings, and you have as many older as you have younger (which is the definition of a Middle Child).

Comment: I agree with the other comments about the meaning and would also like to add that I may say something along the lines of: I'm the eldest child, but I have two brothers, one half, one step. It's worth noting I'd only phrase it like this in a very informal conversation with a native English speaker.